# run ar core sample on avd

Tags: android, augmented-reality, arcore

I'm trying to run ar core sample on avd, but face this message: "The application requires the latest version of ARCore". I'm trying to run on Google Pixel2 emulator with API 27, everything is up to date. The android docs say it is possible, but what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install the [ARCore x86 for emulator apk](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/releases/download/v1.2.1/ARCore_1_2_x86_for_emulator.apk) from the [ARCore GitHub repository](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/releases).

You can then drag the downloaded apk onto the running emulator, or you can run:

`adb install -r ARCore_1_2_x86_for_emulator.apk`

https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/emulator#update_arcore

Comment: After installing this APK emulator saying to install ARCore latest version?

Answer (score 0):

Try using google PIXEL with API 28(or higher) and install [ARCore x86 apk for emulators](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/releases) or download it form [here](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/releases/download/v1.2.1/ARCore_1_2_x86_for_emulator.apk) .
Use this [link](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/emulator#update_arcore) for more help.